# Bad character range in python

Tags: python, regex

I am getting bad character range for the following pattern. why?
Please correct it

```
"^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,6}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's this: `[\w-\.]+` - looks like in Python you need to escape the hyphen: `[\w\-\.]+`.
Other flavors don't interpret it as a range and match the hyphen as part of the character class.

Comment: Or move the hyphen to the very end (or start) of the character class.  Good catch +1.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - Good point, `[\w\.-]+` would also work. I usually prefer to escape hyphens in character sets because I think it's a little more robust, but it's just a matter of style.

Comment: I would argue exactly the opposite, because if you use many regex implementations (not just Python's) there is no way to know really whether backslashes do what you want in a character range.